# Definitions in terms of universal property

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, category-theory

The books on abstract algebra before ~ 1970 and after it differ with one way of writing some mathematical statements. In modern books many definitions are written in terms of certain universal properties (free groups, direct sums, tensor products, etc.).

My question is simple one:

> While studying any branch of abstract algebra, what kind of objects and their definitions *should* one try to understand via their universal properties?

A definition in one book may have been given in terms of universal property, but in some other book, the same definition may have been given without universal property. This suggests one to think of certain kind of objects to be always defined in terms of universal property. I don't know, for what objects we should inquire its universal property.

For example, in a book *Algebra Chapter 0*, the kernel of a homomorphism is also defined in terms of its universal property; I have seen the same in a book on Category Theory. This suggests one to think of some objects in terms of universal property; but, perhaps not every object should be thought in this way, for example, among basic definitions in group theory, no one will try to define quaternion group of order $8$ in terms of a universal property (although it is possible to define - seems from some comments). So, a questions occurs as mentioned above.

Comment: I have a small comment. You should not think of a universal property as a definition, or at least, beware of the following pitfall. Distinguish between the explicit construction, which gives existence, and the universality of the corresponding property, which gives uniqueness, but does not give existence.

Comment: If there are two perspectives, it is best to internalize both. Different circumstances reveal the use of both. Universal properties tend to be very useful when dealing with collections of structures / objects ("naturality", "gluing"), and more concrete constructions / definitions tend to be useful when working with particular elements. But this is not a rule. And of course, even if you define something by a universal property, you have to show that it exists, and this often requires a concrete construction.

Comment: I would not say it's a carefully designed linguistic minefield. (But not because it isn't.)

Comment: FWIW, any presentation of a group can be seen as giving a universal property, so what you say about the quaternion group may not even quite be true.

Comment: With a universal property, there is no need to construct the object in mind explicitly.

Comment: @Carlson: I have edited question regarding your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes proofs are easier when using a universal property. Most of the time you need to use the explicit construction for a proof. It all depends on context.

Both the universal property and explicit construction are necessary for an intuitive understanding of the object. For example, the explicit construction of the tensor product of modules seems strange and unmotivated until you understand the universal property of the tensor product. But if you actually want to work with tensor products, you usually need the explicit construction.

To answer your question, you should know the universal properties of anything called a product, sum, free object, quotient, or tensor product. These objects all behave similarly in their respective categories.